# Typescript is not compiling `node_modules` folder

Tags: typescript

I can't figure out why TypeScript isn't compiling anything that's inside the `node_modules` folder.

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "shared": ["./src/shared"],
      "client": ["./src/client"],
      "server": ["./src/server"],
      "express": ["./node_modules/express"]
    },
    "plugins": [
      {"transform": "ts-transformer-imports"}
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./build"
  },  
  "files": ["./src/server/app.ts"]
}
```

Inside `src/server/app.ts` I import both `express` and `shared`:

```
import shared from 'shared';
import express from 'express';
```

The compilation succeeds, and compiled code for `shared` and `server` are generated. But, for some reason, the code for `express` isn't generated!?

This makes absolutely no sense to me... does it randomly decide to not compile something just because it's in a folder called `node_modules`?

How can I fix this?

**Edit:** I also tried changing it to `"express/*": ["./node_modules/express/*"]` in the config file, which didn't make any difference. (I don't know why it would, but I found that somewhere on the internet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you want to compile a package from node_modules? E.g. ./node_modules/express does NOT contains any TS files. NPM packages usually comes with pre-built (or pre-polyfilled) JS code that you have to just import and use.
If you have trouble importing e.g. something from Express be sure that you've installed the typings (@types/express) as well

Comment: I don't exactly want TypeScript to compile the code in `node_modules/express`, but I want it to add that code to the output folder `"./build"

Comment: I see. I think you shouldn't add to your output - your compiled code can import it from 'node_modules'. Your build/dist/out folders should contain only code from your /src folder. You can read about module resolution here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Comment: Yes, it does make more sense to resolve the modules from `node_modules` at runtime. The problem is, I have separate client and server builds, which share some of the same code. The server build should not have any of the node modules that only the client is using. I was hoping to leave it up to the TypeScript compiler to determine which node modules need to be added to the `build` folder, by going through the import statements in my server code.

Comment: You should take a look at https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/. This allows you to organize your project into e.g. shared, server and client 'workspaces' with shared and separated dependencies as well. You can check TS project references https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html to define the dependencies on each other - but it works still only your packages, not the ones in node_modules.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look